# Append element with another file, with id?

Tags: jquery, append

I need to create simpkle function that get element and append with another file?

With jquery is possbile to do something like this?

```
     $(".overlay-display").click(function (data) {
                        $("#navigation-control").children().remove(data);
                        $.get("include.php", function (data) {
                        $("#navigation-control").append(data);
                    });

            });

     <a class="navbar-toggle overlay-display" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse-bottom-second">Brand</a>

  <div id="navigation-control" class="navbar-collapse-bottom collapse">

  </div>
```

With this solution, all is ok, exectp, that on click div is always append, i want to remove all data from, that element and than include file, is is possible to add file with parametres like this include.php?id=1

And make function like this
 Brand

That way i can always have another file included in element, dependens on data-action attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to include whole file? Is it not better when you will use $.ajax and from that file return HTML code in some function? Then you will can send parameters to that function.

Comment: Read $.ajax documentation. In php u just need to write function which is returning HTML Code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) Or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for your div tag, Like this

```
 $(".overlay-display").click(function () {
                    $.get("include.php", function (data) {
                    $("#navigation-control").empty().append(data);
                    //OR this:
                    //$("#navigation-control").html(data);
                });

        });

 <a class="navbar-toggle overlay-display" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse-bottom-second">Brand</a>

  <div id="navigation-control" class="navbar-collapse-bottom collapse">

  </div>
```

And somthing nice is using [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(".overlay-display").click(function () {
                $("#navigation-control").load('include.php');   
                });

        });

 <a class="navbar-toggle overlay-display" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse-bottom-second">Brand</a>

  <div id="navigation-control" class="navbar-collapse-bottom collapse">

  </div>
```